# how to calculate average for each item in a list with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I calculate each of the averages of the students? I did this ... but the average does not work for me, how could I do it? With a JoinGroup and then a GroupBy ?, I wait to see solutions, thanks.

[image]

```cs
var listadoA = alumnos.Join(examenes, 
                        a => a._id,
                        e => e._alumnoId,
                        (a, e) => new
                        {
                            NombreAlumno = a._nombre,
                            Examenes = examenes,
                            Notas = e._nota,
                        }).Where(p => p.Examenes.Count() >= 1).OrderBy(p => p.NombreAlumno).ToList();
        foreach (var obj in listadoA){
            var promedio = obj.Average(p => p.Nota);
            Console.Write($"\nAlumno = {obj.NombreAlumno}, Promedio ={promedio}");
        }   


class Examen{
    public double _nota{get;set;}
    public int _alumnoId {get;set;}
    public int cursoId{get;set;}


    public Examen(int id, double nota, int idMateria){
        this._alumnoId = id;
        this.cursoId = idMateria;
        this._nota = nota;
    }

    public override string ToString(){
        return ($"Alumno = {this._alumnoId}, Nota = {this._nota}, Curso = {this.cursoId}");
    }
    public static List<Examen> GetLista(){
        return new List<Examen>(){
            new Examen(2,5,1),
            new Examen(4,7,5),
            new Examen(4,9,3),
            new Examen(3,10,4),
            new Examen(7,5,3),
            new Examen(2,8,4),
            new Examen(6,9,5),
            new Examen(9,7,1),
            new Examen(6,5,4),
            new Examen(9,1,4),
            new Examen(7,9,5),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this related to Entity Framework?

Comment: @LaurentGabiot no

Comment: Ok. You should precise what are the types of your objects, because it is not easy to follow, especially with non English variable names. Plus it seems the anonymous object you create has a notas property, that you call Nota after.

Comment: *With a JoinGroup and then a GroupBy ?* - a GroupJoin (if that's what you mean) is a grouping, so you wouldn't need to group you afterwards; you'd groupjoin students to exam results and then you'd have effectively a single object per student with a list of all their exams

Comment: @LaurentGabiot I just added more code, in order to understand and reach the desired solution :)

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the explanation, I did not understand the operation very well

Comment: @imnach0_, thanks for the clarification. Does my answer (which was posted prior to your clarification) helps? In your case there is no need to GroupBy or Join. The average you need doesn't take into account the Curso? (Course I guess?). Is it what you want?

Comment: @LaurentGabiot You can both use the GroupJoin and the Join, it is independent of each person, the grade is in the exam, not in the course, therefore it is not necessary to take it into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit short on time to test it but I think it should work with a few small tweaks. If I've made any typos, let me know:

```
var listadoA = alumnos.GroupJoin(examenes, 
                    a => a._id,
                    e => e._alumnoId,
                    (a, eGroup) => new
                    {
                        Alumno = a,
                        Examenes = eGroup
                        
                    }).Where(p => p.Examenes.Count() >= 1).OrderBy(p => p.Alumno._nombre).ToList();
foreach (var obj in listadoA){
        var promedio = obj.Examenes.Average(e => e._nota);
```

I'm curious why your fields starting with underscore are publicly accessible; that's the naming convention for a private field.. should really have public properties for them. Also, I've assumed that "nota" is the exam score..

Comment: Could you please explain, where alumnos comes from?

Comment: `alumnos` is, I presume, a list of students that imnach0_ has got from somewhere, like maybe `var alumnos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Alumno>(...)`. I assume it might be like `[{1,"John"},{2,"Mary"}]`. In the same way, `examenes` is a list of exams the student has taken, with an ID of the Student, maybe an ID of the Course, and a Score (nota) of the exam. Because there will be multiple Student ID numbers for different courses, and different grades, `examenes` might have data like `[{1,"English",100},{1,"French",80},...]` - the hope is to get the average of the scores (John:90) per student

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

The answer was originaly posted before precisions were made about the classes involved. I still keep the english naming, because it might be clearer for a wider audience. This also helps clarify my answer in regards to @Caius Jard pertinent comment.

Using Linq to object: (no use of Entity Framework)

This code does the following tradeof compared to the use of join. It might be less performant, but it is more simple (you don't even have to understand what a join is).

```cs
AveragesByStudents = Students
    .Select(s => new 
    {
        StudentName = s.Name,
        Notes = Exams
            .Where(e => e.StudentId == s.Id)
            .Select(e => e.Note)
            .ToList()
    })
    .Select(s => new 
    {
        s.StudentName,
        Average = s.Notes.Any() ? s.Notes.Average() : null
    });
;
```

With this example, you obtain all the students, even if they have no notes (in that case their average is null). You could do it in one select, but it would not be more readable.

With the following example, you obtain only the students that have notes, so their average cannot be null.

```cs
AveragesByStudents = Students
    .Select(s => new 
    {
        StudentName = s.Name,
        Notes = Exams
            .Where(e => e.StudentId == s.Id)
            .Select(e => e.Note)
    })
    .Where(s => s.Notes.Any())
    .Select(s => new 
    {
        s.StudentName,
        Average = Notes.Average()
    });
;
```

Add a ToList() at the end of queries if you want to materialize.

Comment: apply your solution but it throws an error, which does not contain elements ..

Comment: Yes, I forgot the case where there is no Exam for a student, let me correct this

Comment: This should work too, but I did want to make one small note for future readers , that it might not be as efficient as a GroupJoin because there isn't really any way LINQ can know the intention is a join. For example this approach would likely repeatedly enumerate the exams looking for matching entries in a nested loops style. A GroupJoin can know it's worth enumerating grouped side and stashing the results in a lookup device for faster retrieval of matching entities

Comment: @Caius Jard, I edited my answer to reflect your comment.